# Insert a string based on differing occurence counts of strings in python

Tags: python, text, sentiment-analysis

I hope someone can help me with the following.

Assuming I have the following text (more precise - a code chunk from a latex table).

- text = "Some **&** random **&** content **\** Some **&** further **&** content **\** …. "

Next, I would like to place the string inside of the text based on two input factors, inside of the text with one specifying the row based on \ and the other the column based on &.

So in case of the the pair **(1,1)** the string should be placed before the first occurrence of  \ and the first occurrence of &. 
(1, 1, “HERE”, text) as input should return:

- **HERESome** & not coloured & content \ Some & further & content \ ….

And for 
(2, 2, “HERE”, text)  should return

- Some & not coloured & content \ Some & **HEREfurther** & content \ ….

Ideally the function would also take multiple pairs with inputs, so with 1,1 and 2,2 as input:

- **HERESome** & not coloured & content \ Some & **HEREfurther** & content \ ….

should be the outcome.

My current approach does not treats & and \ different. 
and HERE does not appear in front.

```py
text = "Some & random & content \\ Some & further & content \\ …. "

def replacenth(string, sub, wanted, n):
    pattern = re.compile(sub)
    where = [m for m in pattern.finditer(string)][n-1]
    before = string[:where.start()]
    after = string[where.start():]
    newString = before + wanted + after
    return newString

replacenth(text, "[&\\+]", "HERE" , 2)

#output: 
#'Some & random HERE& content \\ Some & further & content \\ …. '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). No checking for bad input though.

```
def replace(string, sub, row_col_pairs):
    rows = string.split(' \\ ')
    for row, col in row_col_pairs:
        cells = rows[row-1].split(' & ')
        cells[col-1] = sub+cells[col-1]
        rows[row-1] = ' & '.join(cells)
    return ' \\ '.join(rows)

replace(text, "HERE", [(1, 3), (2, 2)])

# output
# Some & random & HEREcontent \ Some & HEREfurther & content \ ….
```

Comment: Great! That looks perfect, looking forward to try it out.